# putClientPropery without specifying class

Tags: java, swing, properties

I am trying to set the client property for a collection of swing objects. The objects are JFormattedTextField, JButton, and JComboBox. Is there a way to do this without specifically finding which class each is?

```
HashMap<Integer,Object> fieldList = getTimeline(step_);
for (Object entry : fieldList.values()) {
    entry.putClientProperty("step",i+1);
}
```

Is there some other/better way to change client properties for collection of swing objects? TIA

Comment: Why not `HashMap<Integer, JComponent>`?

Comment: ^--- Basically is the right answer because `putClientProperty` is only defined in a `JComponent`, so it's the lowest common denominator

Comment: Thanks trashgod. I was not aware that was acceptable but it has simplified my code. However, it has created a new problem in my extension of JFormattedTextField when I add a listener. I have posted that as a new question.

Comment: Never mind. I figured out the problem. Thanks again.